# Redirect Keyboard input with XGrabKey or XGrabKeyboard

Tags: c++, keyboard, xlib

### Goal

I want to **redirect the keyboard input** to different windows depending on the key. Not all the key will be redirected to the same window, I can't use `XSetInputFocus`.

---

### First Attempt : XGrabKey

I found that I can grab certain keys and then send an event to the right window.
I used [XGrabKey](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html) like this

```
XGrabKey( mDisplay(), 
                    XKeysymToKeycode(mDisplay(),XK_F1) , 
                    AnyModifier ,
                    RootWindow(mDisplay(), mScreenNum),
                    false, //Events aren't sent to the focused window
                    GrabModeAsync, 
                    GrabModeAsync );
```

**It doesn't work for F1 to F4 keys**, but it does for F5 and F6. It also doesn't work for some regular keys like e, r and t. There may be others.
I need to be able to redirect the Fkeys, so this solution didn't work for me.

---

### Second Attempt : XGrabKeyboard

I tried with [XGrabKeyboard](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKeyboard.html), like this

```
XGrabKeyboard(mDisplay(), 
                        RootWindow(mDisplay(), mScreenNum),
                        false, 
                        GrabModeAsync, 
                        GrabModeAsync, 
                        CurrentTime);
```

It works with all the Fkeys, but it created other problems. When the grab keyboard is active I can no longer move the windows with my mouse (it still works if the application move its window), I can't access to context menus and the blinking '|' isn't displayed in typing areas.

### Other informations

This problem as already been talked about [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555703/x11-unable-to-move-window-after-xgrabkeyboard), but they didn't find a solution.I am using Lubuntu(LXDE) and not GNOME and **I still have the same problem**.

#### The unmap event may give some informations:

> - When the keyboard **is not grabbed** and I right click
>
>   the context menu is displayed, no unmap event.
> - When I exit the context menu :
>
>   I have 3 unmap events : (I print the name of the window next to Unmap)

```
Unmap pcmanfm  
Unmap pcmanfm 
Unmap
```

> - When the keyboard **is grabbed** and I right click
>
>   I have just 1 unmap event :

```
Unmap
```

It looks like the context menu is **unmapped before it is displayed**.

---

### What I am asking for

I would like to **either**:

- Use XGrabKeyboard without side effects
- Use XGrabKey with any key
- Use another fonction that would allow me to redirect keyboard input

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for the XGrabKeyboard problem.

The XGrabKey failed for some keys because they were already grabbed by OpenBox. Openbox has some built-in hotkeys that use XGrabKey. Because I use `AnyModifier`, if any grab has been made that include this key then the grab will fail.

For example if a program grabs `Ctrl+F1` you can't grab F1 with AnyModifier. You can grab F1 without modifier, but the grab will not be active if the user press `Alt+F1` for example.

To correct this problem I removed the keyboard hotkeys of Openbox because they were not important to me. To do so I modified the [configuration file](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_bindings).

The other solution is to grab the key with all the modifier but the one that is already grabbed. Grabbing the key without modifier isn't enough because for example Num-Lock is a modifier and you probably don't want your grab to be active or not depending on Num-Lock.

Comment: But this is a solution to the __main goal__, right?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Yes it is the solution I used for the problem I had.